# React Native - I can't get a response from my FETCH, but my api does get the data i post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I tried many things, it will only POST to the api when it has "mode: no-cors" and no headers.

I am now trying with mode: 'cors', because i've read that i shouldn't use 'no-cors' because of security reasons. BUT, i do have to remove the headers or else it won't POST the data.

Here's the code:

```
signUp: async(email, password)=> {
  
  let values = {
    firstname: "pruebaNombre",
    lastname: "pruebaApellido",
    email: email,
    password: password
  }
  const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    // headers: { 
    //   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    //   'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    // },
    body: JSON.stringify(values),
  }
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost/rest-api-authentication-example/API/create_user.php', config);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);   
}
```

The console.log(data) should be a json with a message saying "user was created", but i get these errors:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/rest-api-authentication-example/API/create_user.php' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost/rest-api-authentication-example/' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

The data does get posted on my server, but i can't get a the response from the fetch.

EDITED.- These are my headers on my server side:

> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/rest-api-authentication-example/");
>
> header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
>
> header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
>
> header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
>
> header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

Comment: Can you update your question to include your CORS configuration in your server

Comment: @rantao ok i just edited it

Answer (score 0):

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost/rest-api-authentication-example/' that is not equal to the supplied origin

Try adding `proxy: "http://localhost:${PORT}"` to your React-Native `package.json` where PORT is your server port

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a little lost. Where should i declare the variable PORT? and, will i still use the same url when using fetch?

Comment: Hey! i just solved it by changing the header to: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); Will that be a good solution? because its working now :)

Comment: For development purposes that is fine, but I wouldn't recommend for a production app. Changing to `*` essentially lets anyone/domain make requests to your server, which is a security risk

Comment: PORT is just the port number of your server, so for example if your server port is `3001`, it would be `proxy: "http://localhost:3001`

Comment: Thanks! will have to change it later then, for now i'm just trying to make it work haha